# Watching hashtags with tweepy after API Update

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, bots, tweepy

Twitter is updating their API and by updating they mean shutting down some services such as the Streaming API. 
Sadly enough, I am using these streaming APIs on my bot to watch either messages posted with a certain hashtag and messages sent by mentionning the account or commands sent by direct messages.

And I found no idea on how to migrate to the new API. Any idea ?

For now I'm using this :

```
mainStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener= mainStreamListener())
mainStream.filter(track=[Hashtag], is_async=True)

cmdStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener= cmdStreamListener())
cmdStream.userstream(is_async=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one of the two streaming APIs that you are using is currently about to be removed (user streams is being removed, filter is not, but is on [Twitter's roadmap for replacement in the future](https://trello.com/c/dwCWo22Y/21-a-more-flexible-and-powerful-endpoint-to-replace-statuses-filter)).

If you are interested in how to migrate to the Account Activity API, Twitter has a migration guide [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/migration/introduction). The basic principle is that your code would need to register a webhook and subscription for the user's account activity messages, and then respond to Direct Message events (instead of the code you're currently implementing in the `cmdStream` section). I do not know whether the tweepy library currently has specific support for the Account Activity API.

Comment: Oh man I am so happy then. 
There will be work to do but at least I can continue working properly.